# Initializing global session variable on selection of dropdown value

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a page where there is a `dropdownlist`.

Now what I want is, whenever I select the value from `dropdownlist`. *A global session should get initialized*. how to do that in asp.net.

Here is my code

```
<td align="right" width="8%">
  <span class="xy8">Warehouse :</span>
</td>
<td align="center">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPreferencesWh" runat="server" Width="150"> </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

How to do that in asp.net. whenever I select any value from the dropdownlist

**UPDATED**

Code behind;-

```
protected void Bindwarehouse()
{
    DataTable dtregion = CF.ExecuteDT("select Type_Desc, Master_Mkey from type_mst_a where type_code='WH'");
    ddlPreferencesWh.DataTextField = "Type_Desc";
    ddlPreferencesWh.DataValueField = "Master_Mkey";
    ddlPreferencesWh.DataSource = dtregion;
    ddlPreferencesWh.DataBind();
    ddlPreferencesWh.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---Select---", "0"));
}
```

Comment: Add `SelectedIndexChanged` event in your dropdownlist. What the global session will do if initialized?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: added like `ddlPreferencesWh_OnSelectedIndexChanged` now what should I write in code behind to generate a session ?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: It will create a session for the whole site.

Comment: Will the session value be same for all user's or particular user.

Comment: No, it will be different for each value from the dropdownlist. as each value has a unique key. See my updated question

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal: whenever the user changes the value from the dropdown, the session will get updated and it will redirect to the home page. OK ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dropdownlist has a method called "*selectedIndexChanged*". When even someone changes the drodown list's selected index, this method will fired in the server side.

To call the server side method in your dropdownlist please use the below code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="YourMethodinServerSide">
```

sever side method -

```
protected void YourMethodinServerSide(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

in this "YourMethodinServerSide" method you can write your code to initiate the session by creating a session variable.

```
Session["variable_name"]=ddl.selectedindex.value;
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
```

So whenever you change the dropdownlist value, **Session["variable_name"]** will get updated.

*If you have a base class for managing the sessions, then you can pass the dropdownlist value to that class.*

Comment: how will I know whether the session is created or not ??

Comment: When you add a value to a session variable it will create the session. If you want to check the value in the session, you can use the below code.
if(Session["variable_name"]!=null)

Normally session is created when you run the web application. What you are doing here is adding a variable to the session.

Comment: what i want is `whenever the user changes the value from the dropdown, the session will get updated and it will redirect to the home page`

Comment: Yes. So you write your code in "SelectedIndexChanged" method in the server side. Please use this to create selected index changed even.
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="YourMethodinServerSide">

then inside "YourMethodinServerSide" you write the assignment part and the redirection.

Session["variable_name"]=dropdownlist.selectedindex.value;
Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");

Comment: so when, `again if I go to the preference page and reselect the value will the session get updated ???`

Comment: Yes. It will get updated. **make sure you use the exact same variableName.** otherwise it will create a new session value.

Comment: can you post a new answer so that it can make clear and will check also. or you can update it so that i can make a clear vsion of it

Comment: @karun: what if I want to set the value selected if I again come to this page from home page ???

Comment: you mean to say, you want to programmatically select the dropdown value to the earlier selected value which you stored in the session?